# access type variable values in instance declaration

Tags: haskell

I have a `newtype` wrapping a function

```hs
newtype Operation a b = Operation (a -> b)
```

I would like to write a `Show` instance for this datatype providing information like `"Operation(Int -> String)"`. To do this I would need to access the value of the type variables `a` and `b` in the implementation of `show`. Is this possible?

I would say no, but Haskell never stops to amaze me, so I thought I might ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let me say that this is a bad idea: `Show` instances should actually give you the contents/value, not just information about the type.

Anyway though...

```
import Data.Typeable

instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Show (Operation a b) where
  show (Operation f) = "«Operation("++show (typeOf f)++")»"
```

Comment: thanks. I agree it's not the best idea to provide such a Show instance. I'm using QuickCheck and I'd like to use `Operation` as the `a` in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:forAll, which requires a `Show` instance

Comment: @marcosh For QuickCheck, you almost certainly want [Function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html) instead.